# Mount EXT2 Filesystem to cygwin

Tags: filesystems, cygwin

I have an external USB drive that is formatted as a Linux EXT2 filesystem. It has a lot of data on it and I don't want to format the drive. I do the drive with a drive letter assign in Windows Explorer, but I am not able to open it. I can read the contents using the diskInternals Linux Reader application. What I want to do is to see this drive in Cygwin. When I execute df in Cygwin I see many of my drives listed, but not the EXT2 drive. How do I see this drive in Cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

CYGWIN is a user space program. It is not a able to mount different filesystem not recognized by Windows.

Third party program could be able or you can use WSL